# Neo4j doesn't start after copying new *.db

Tags: neo4j

I have Neo4j 3.2 community edition running on my machine (Linux) and it works usually just fine. After copying of the *.db directory from my colleague and pointing to this new datastore, the database doesn't want to start anymore.

By repointing to old one everything works again. I have already checked with pgrep neo4j for other running instances, but haven't found any.

I get following errors in my neo4j.log:

```
2017-07-28 13:29:23.157+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1799f9ab' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1799f9ab' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1799f9ab' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:219)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:28)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1799f9ab' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, .../databases/bird_molecules.db
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:209)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:124)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:58)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery@5b0c5b15' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:416)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:62)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:511)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:205)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized log entry version -10. At position LogPosition{logVersion=44, byteOffset=16} and entry version null
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.LogEntryVersion.byVersion(LogEntryVersion.java:162)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.VersionAwareLogEntryReader.readLogEntry(VersionAwareLogEntryReader.java:97)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.LogEntryCursor.next(LogEntryCursor.java:54)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.LatestCheckPointFinder.find(LatestCheckPointFinder.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.PositionToRecoverFrom.apply(PositionToRecoverFrom.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.DefaultRecoverySPI.getPositionToRecoverFrom(DefaultRecoverySPI.java:81)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.recovery.Recovery.init(Recovery.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:406)
    ... 18 more
2017-07-28 13:29:23.157+0000 INFO  Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

Comment: Try edit the neo4j.conf file, uncomment the line `#dbms.active_database=graph.db` and change `graph.db` to `bird_molecules.db`. The final line will be `dbms.active_database=bird_molecules.db`.

Comment: Hello @BrunoPeres, that's exactly what I've meant with "pointing to data store". So I have already edited the neo4j.conf. Each time I configure noe4j to use the new data store, it doesn't start. Configuring back to use the old one - and it works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of my problems were different versions of Neo4j used by me and my colleague. He created the database on a 3.2.1 and I have tried to use it with a 3.2.0 instance. After installing the last 3.2.2 version, I can use the new data store without problems.